# Parameter in TTURLMap?

Tags: iphone, delegates, three20

I have a Facebook-Like MainScreen.
For my SettingsViewController I need to pass a object for my delegate throughout the method.

How to do this?

Here is my code until now:

```
TTURLMap* map = navigator.URLMap; 

 [map            from: @"tt://einstellungen"
              parent: @"tt://launcher"
    toViewController: [SettingsViewController class]
            selector: nil
          transition: trans];



NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                  [self launcherItemWithTitle:@"Einstellungen"
                                        image:@"bundle://animexx-72.png"
                                          URL:@"tt://einstellungen"]                  
                  , nil];  

launcherView.pages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      array
                      , nil];
```

Normaly I would have:

```
SettingsViewController *controller = [SettingsViewController alloc] init];
controller.delegate = self;
```

How to have this here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the controller as an object, you can initialize it and use the object reference in the TTURLMap:

```
 SettingsViewController* controller = [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];
 controller.delegate = self;


 [map            from: @"tt://einstellungen"
              parent: @"tt://launcher"
    toViewController: controller
            selector: nil
          transition: trans];
```